# Change class on scrolling menu, first click issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scroll, menu

I want to have scrolling one page menu that will have smaller height on scrolling (after certain point). Here is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var menu = $('.menuclass');
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        var y = $(this).scrollTop();
        var z = $('.someclass').offset().top;
        if (y >= z) {
            menu.removeClass('nav1').addClass('nav2');
        } else {
            menu.removeClass('nav2').addClass('nav1');
        }
    });
});
```

Class nav1 has height 120px and class nav2 has height 60px

Everything works fine, except that, on first scrolling (click) to first anchor point, there is a problem that menu overlaps section like it still has 120px height instead of 60px that should have from new class. I suppose script already used first height to count. On second scrolling, problem disappears.

How can I add a size of 60px in script to be count even in first time of script activation?

Comment: fiddle? we need to see/debug it

Answer (score 0):

Could you show your code in fiddle, with relevant CSS and HTML included?
JS code you posted shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: things like that belongs to comment section.

Answer (score 0):

It was a conflict with sticky.js script for sticky menu. It was called on same div as script for changing classes. I removed it and problem disappeared. Instead I'm using css only, position: fixed; for menu.